# Enum value dependant function call

Tags: c++, enums, constant-expression

Here is simplified setup of my application:

```
class Engine {
    void run(); { // main program loop
        while (state != gameState::quit)
            step<state>(); // ERROR
    }

    template<gameState>
    void step() {} // empty default step function

    template<>
    void step<gameState::intro>() { /* do step for intro state*/ }
    template<>
    void step<gameState::menu>() { /* do step for menu state*/ }

    gameState state;
}
```

What I want to do is call the step function dependant on the current value in state member. In step() call, the state isn't a constant expression which is a problem. Is there a way to write this enum dependant function call without some big ugly switch?

(This is only a simplified example with one function and only 2 states).

Comment: Your step template is inherently a compile-time construct, and run() selection is inherently a runtime construct. You can't just mix the two. You can apply some metaprogramming to enumerate all the possible states in compile-time and generate some runtime switchboard. Or you can use one of the existing libraries which do that like Boost MSM.

Comment: [This article](https://kfrlib.com/blog/how-c14-and-c17-help-to-write-faster-and-better-code-real-world-examples/) mentions a `cswitch` template that could propably be used for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't avoid using `switch` when using state which is not `constexpr`. This is the nature of state machines. All you can do is try to make it look less ugly:

```
void dispatch_state(gameState st) {
    switch(st) {
        case gameState::intro: handle_intro(); break;
        case gameState::menu:  handle_menu(); break;
        // etc...
    }
}
```

UPD: there are other dispatch techniques, e.g. storing an array of function pointers as @KonstantinL suggested, or having an `std::map` of `std::function`s, but each of them requires you to manually write down a table with enumerators and corresponding handlers. Among all of them I prefer the one with minimum indirection, which is plain old `switch`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried to write it with array of functions but the array initialization in engine ctor was as long as using switch but much uglier

Comment: Ok so I've wrapped all the state dependant functions that are called in the main program loop into a templated loop function, which I call just like you in your example inside the switch. Thanks for help.